# Why do I get the following error in initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have this in my  main code , 
and It will give error because of too many data in initialization. 
I can't change int ** point phrase. how can initialize it?

```
int** points = { { 3, 6, 1, 4 }, { 17, 15, 1, 4 }, { 13, 15, 1, 4 }, { 6, 12, 1, 4 },
{ 9, 1 ,1,4}, { 2, 7,1,4 }, { 10, 19,1,4 } };
```

thank you in advance

Comment: An array is not a pointer and vice versa.

Comment: so If I want to initialize it I should use loop or something like that?

Comment: Change `int** points` to `int points[][4]`.

Comment: I have said, it said I should use int ** points =

Comment: it is my project :((

Comment: Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times: "A pointer is not an array."

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is the following:)

```
int **points = new int *[7] 
{ 
    new int[4] {  3,  6, 1, 4 }, new int[4] { 17, 15, 1, 4 }, new int[4] { 13, 15, 1, 4 }, 
    new int[4] {  6, 12, 1, 4 }, new int[4] {  9,  1, 1, 4 }, new int[4] {  2,  7, 1, 4 }, 
    new int[4] { 10, 19, 1, 4 } 
};
```

Take into account that you need explicitly to free all allocated memory when the arrays will not be needed any more.

For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) delete [] points[i];
delete [] points;
```

You could also use a pointer declared like

```
int ( *points )[4];
```

In this case you could indeed allocate dynamically a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @SepidHosseini The compiler must to support C++ 2011.

Answer (score 0):

If you must keep `points` a pointer to a pointer, you can initialize it like this:

```
// Construct the individual sub-arrays for the nested dimension
int pt0[] = {  3,  6, 1, 4 };
int pt1[] = { 17, 15, 1, 4 };
int pt2[] = { 13, 15, 1, 4 };
int pt3[] = {  6, 12, 1, 4 };
int pt4[] = {  9,  1, 1, 4 };
int pt5[] = {  2,  7, 1, 4 };
int pt6[] = { 10, 19, 1, 4 };
// Construct an array of pointers
int* pts[] = { pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6 };
// Convert an array of pointers to a double-pointer
int** points = pts;
```

This assumes static initialization context (e.g. global variables). If the context is not static, using `points` must be confined to the scope of the inner arrays to which it points. For example, you cannot return `points` from a function.

If you want to return a pointer from a function, you could use `static`, like this:

```
static int pt0[] = {  3,  6, 1, 4 };
static int pt1[] = { 17, 15, 1, 4 };
...
static int* pts[] = { pt0, pt1, ... };
int** points = pts; // no "static" here
...
return points;
```

Note, however, that the function will be returning the same pointer every time that you call it.

Comment: Be careful of that answer:  `points` becomes invalid when the variables used to initialize it go out of scope.  Depending on your intended use of `points` that might be a problem.

Comment: The edit to the answer saying static or global addresses the issue of those going out of scope too soon, but creates new problems (restrictions on what may be correct use of `points`)

Comment: @JSF If `points` is in global or static scope, they remain valid for the duration of the program.

Comment: yeah, it does not  work when I want to change it and return it from a function. it is so easy if I could use vector ,or normal array. these dynamic arrays are the hardest for me

Comment: @SepidHosseini If you want to return it from a function, you could add `static` in front of the arrays being initialized (edited).